# Measuring a 9volt battery with a D.Multimeter

Tags: batteries, multimeter

I try to measure a 9volt battery and it displays "9.14V". But the battery is empty. What is happening? Does the multimeter measures it's own 9V battery?

Can someone explain to me what i observe? How does a completely empty battery acts in a circuit with a multimeter?

EDIT
When I connect a LED (without resistors) the battery is able to light it a bit, and then the multimeter displays 8.8V and falling. But if I disconnect the LED the voltage measured starts rising again until it reaches 9.15V again...

The weird thing is that the battery is almost empty.

Comment: An empty battery acts like it's empty. Stick it across your tongue. If it hurts, the meter is right. If it doesn't, the meter is wrong.

Comment: No, the battery is not empty. Connect a LED in series with a 1 kohm resistor across the battery terminals, the LED should light up. If not reverse the polarity. How can an empty battery make a LED light up? The battery might not be able to deliver enough current for a different application but it is not empty.

Comment: Thanks, this battery that displays 9.15V gives a small feeling in the tongue but it is not able to rotate a small motor. Another one that measures 4.5V rotates the motor fine...

Comment: When a battery gets depleted, its **internal resistance** increases meaning the voltage **drops** when a (demanding, current hungry) load is connected. The battery can still drive a light load though like a LED.

Comment: And motors are well known for needing a lot of current....

Comment: Yes but why it displays 9.15V, why there is no voltage drop if it is depleted?

Comment: What voltage does it read when trying to drive the motor?

Comment: Because of the voltage drop across **the internal resistance**. When you **measure** the voltage, almost **no current** flows. Then the battery can deliver 9 V easily. But connect a motor which might need 0.1 A for example and the voltage drop across the internal resistance increases because now **a large** current flows (wants to flow). But really, 9V batteries are **no good** for motors. Better use 6 AA cells in series. See here: http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/batteryir.pdf  for a **technical explanation** of internal resistance.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what i observe that I haven't noticed again. By my experience a 9V battery (or any battery)  with usage starts to provide a smaller voltage until it is empty. When I connect the motor the voltage measured drops to 0. But why it registers 9V without a load connected? And why all the other 9V batteries behave "normal" i.e. display a lower voltage in a measurement without a load

Comment: @EML I would prefer if I was able to test the capacity of my batteries with a multimeter instead of using my tongue. Imagine I go to vacation and I need to take some batteries with me. I measure them with my multimeter and it displays "9V", I go to my camp and I finally found my batteries empty...

Comment: *But why it registers 9V without a load connected? And why all the other 9V batteries behave "normal* That has to do with the way you discharge the battery, you discharge it quickly with the motor and that means you can only get less than half out of the battery, a lot of energy is still in the battery. Give the battery some time without a load and it will recover. It is a **complex chemical process** which causes this behavior.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks. Can you give me a hint why just one battery provides me the "wrong" measurement and all other batteries I have appear "normal". i.e. I have 5 batteries here. All used. When measured all the batteries display a voltage according to their capacity, for an example 4.5 V. I can use this battery to power a motor and it works. I know that this battery is kind of depleted but there is still some energy inside. But one battery that is just capable to light a LED without resistor... displays 9.15V. What is different in this battery?

Comment: I answered that in my previous comment: *It is a complex chemical process which causes this behavior.* By discharging it quickly you "chemically damaged" the battery in such a way that it can no longer deliver high currents. It can only deliver small currents because the internal resistance has become very high due to the damage. 9V batteries (the small ones) are **unsuited** to power motors. The current damages them (as you've experienced). You need a more powerful battery to power the motor like 6 AA cells in series. AA cells can easily supply 0.5 A or so for some time. A 9V battery cannot.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ok, now I understand, thanks. But I have used all my batteries the same way. In general i'm not trying to drive a motor. I just use a small motor to test if the batteries have any energy inside. And most probably I have driven such small motors for a small time with any of the mentioned batteries. So I can understand that the "chemical damage" is kind of unpredictable and it can happens now or then (because all the other batteries do not seem affected of this "chemical damage". Anyway, I suppose I have to study about batteries a bit. Thanks again

Comment: *So I can understand that the "chemical damage" is kind of unpredictable* Only if you load the batteries too much for too much time. Look at this datasheet: https://d2ei442zrkqy2u.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Ultra-Power_9V_MX1604.pdf  Note how at 250 mA, battery life is less than 2 hours. For a 9 V battery I'd stay below 50 mA peak current and a long time average current less than a few mA. Are your batteries all same brand and model? All same age? Only then can you compare fairly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the voltage of a battery measured with a DM may be misleading, since there is nearly no power/current required. To get a better picture of the battery state, the voltage should be measured while the battery is connected to the application, in this case to the motor. Probably that battery can be still used for other applications that do not demand a high current, f.e. clocks, weather stations, remote controls etc. Sometimes if a battery is used for a high power application for a short time, it can relax and show a higher voltage than before after disconnecting and waiting some time. Also the heat that may be produced during the high load can increase the voltage if measured without the load. This relaxation process, i.e. a possible higher voltage as expected may occur under certain conditions like manufacturing/formation issues, storage history, load profile, temperature etc. In some cases, the application provides a tiny backflow into the battery if the battery power is not needed, f.e. if the application electronics has also a mains power supply or another battery and/or has a fault or is made for rechargable batteries. In that case a nearly empty battery may also show a misleading high voltage if measured with a DM without load.

Answer (score 1):

To a rough approximation, an ordinary zinc or alkaline battery looks like a perfect voltage source with a resistor in series with it.  As the battery runs down, this internal resistance increases.  The voltage only drops significantly when the battery is totally flat.

A digital multimeter has a very high resistance, usually about 10 Mohm.  This is much higher than the internal resistance of the battery, so you read the true voltage of the battery.

If you connect a load, then the voltage at the terminals of the battery drops because the internal resistance is in series with the load.

Answer (score 1):

That’s exactly how a nearly empty battery will behave: with a very small load (a multimeter) it puts out it’s nominal voltage (slightly over 9 volts in this case); with a heavier load (an LED directly across the terminals, or a motor) the output voltage drops because the battery can’t provide enough power for the heavier load.